# Is there a Shim solution (like Microsoft Fakes) that is compatible with xUnit?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes, shim

I'm looking for a good .Net Shim solution for unit testing that is compatible with xUnit. I've used Pose before (https://github.com/tonerdo/pose), but it only occasionally works - I have run into multiple cases where it fails to generate working CIL (you just get a System.InvalidProgramException when the test executes). Based on the project's forum, this is apparently a known issue for some time now, supposedly fixed a couple of times, but still open because it keeps coming up.

So, I'm looking for a more reliable Shim solution. It must be usable from xUnit, because that is the unit testing framework imposed upon the department - apparently our automated build pipeline has some kind of issues that I don't know the details of with the QualityTools assembly, so that's not an option for us. Pose is great when it works, but I have run into too many instances where it didn't work, and I'm looking for something more reliable.